# Remove Special Chars and Word chars after Special Chars followed by Whitespace in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

If the title not clear, here is the examples

I want to remove all the Special Characters in a String, a word character after special character followed by a white space.

```
String = "Here is the world's first movie. #movie";
```

with the above example, I need the output like

```
"Here is the world first movie movie";
```

I tried many regex to achieve this, but I can't I tried following

```
replaceAll("[^\\w]\\w{1}\\s", " ");
```

but it's not working, can you tell me the Regex for this with explanation.

thanks in advance

**Edit:** requirement is I want to remove the special character like in `#movie`, and also want to remove special character with a single character followed by a space like in `world's favorite` the final output should be `world favorite`.

MOST PROBABLY THE CHARACTER AFTER A SPECIAL CHARS WILL BE `'s'`. for example 
`world's, India's, john's`

Comment: Assume the # is your special character... after #movie is no whitespace. So the source is wrong. Your output is missing a `.`. Please review.

Comment: Works fine for me (replacing `'s`), did you remember to assign the result of `replaceAll` back to something?

Comment: Are you removing special characters if they are followed by none, one or more word chars and then a space, so that the `'s`, `.` are replaced but not the `#movie` since there's no space after it? Meaning something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/mH7aY0)?

Comment: @PeterRader I want to remove all non Word character, so no `.` in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it to work by many trial and error, The Final Regex String is `[^a-zA-Z\\s]s?(\\s)?`

`str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]s?(\\s)?", "$1");`

Here is the Explanation,

`[^a-zA-Z\\s]s?` => Find all the special character except White space, follwed by one or zero `s`

`(\\s)?` => and immediately followed by a one or zero White space.

Here I grouped `(\\s)` becoz I want to use that in the `replaceAll()` function as 2nd Parameter to replace as `$1`.

The Answer is

```
String orig = "Here is the world's first movie. #movie";`
System.out.println(orig..replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]s?(\\s)?", "$1"));
```

Final Output will be `Here is the world first movie movie`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "Here is the world's first movie. #movie";
    String output = input.replaceAll("[!@#$%^&*][a-z]+", "");
    System.out.println(output);
```

Regex - [!@#$%^&*][a-z]+

```
   [!@#$%^&*] - tests for special character for the first character
   [a-z]+ - tests for word
```

Comment: While that does take care of `#movie`, it should also take care of [`. `] (don't forget the white space), but `#movie` isn't followed by a white space, so either the source is wrong or the requirements are wrong - Just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer What I want is remove all Special Characters as `[!@#$%^&*.,:;]`, remove special char and next word or any character until space like `world's most` final output should be "world most"